# PL/SQL PLS-00103 on adding two variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm new to pl/sql and trying to print even numbers up till 100 using the following code:

```
Declare
    i number;
    sum number:=0;
    x number:=2;
    n number;
Begin
    for i in 1..100 loop
        if (i%x=0) then
            n:=i;       
            sum:=sum+n;
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(sum);
end;
```

i get this error

```
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following:
(
ORA-06550: line 13, column 26:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
(
```

Help? :(

There is no % operator in PL/SQL; use the mod(i,x) function instead. Anyway, you don't need the n variable. sum:=sum+i will do. sum might be a reserved word, use s instead.
\

Now:

```
  Declare
    i number;
    sum number:=0;
Begin
    for i in 1..100 loop
        if (mod(i,2)=0) then   
                sum:=sum+i;
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(sum);
end;
```

sameproblem :(

Answer (score 5):

There is no % operator in PL/SQL; use the `mod(i,x)` function instead. Anyway, you don't need the n variable. `sum:=sum+i` will do. But: `sum` is a PL/SQL [keyword](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm), use s instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare
i number;
sum1  number:=0; 
x number:=2;
n number;
Begin
for i in 1..100 loop
if(i mod x =0)then
n:=i;  
sum1:=sum1+n;
end if;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(sum1);
end;
/
```

## Reason :

The "sum" is one of the aggregate function ,so we can't use this as variable name.